# ps2pdf produces /undefined in Blue when setting gridlabelcolor to dvipsnames' Blue

Tags: pstricks

latex-dvips-ps2pdf compilation sequence produces a weird result when I change the grid style. The problem does not happen when I compile the same code with xelatex.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}


\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridcolor=Red!20,
    gridlabelcolor=Blue,
    subgridcolor=Green!20
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

With latex-dvips-ps2pdf:

[image]

With xelatex:

[image]

### The latest edit

It seems to me this problem has been fixed by a package or class author silently. I have just tried and the problem disappeared!

Comment: I get a Ghostscript error if I do `simpdftex latex test` (which is a wrapper for `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`). The PDF is produced, but the error is `/undefined in Blue`.

Comment: with current TL2012 everything is fine with xelatex and ps2pdf

Comment: @Herbert: Why are the grid labels not in math mode? I noticed the minus sign looks like a hyphen.

Comment: the grid is done on PS side. If you want it like LaTeXs math mode then suppress the labels on PS side and use `\psaxes`

Comment: @Herbert: One more: What is the reason of putting the job of rendering the grid labels in the PS level rather than in TeX level?

Comment: historical reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in some special cases the color definition table is missing in the pdf output. In such cases a

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,pstricks,border=12pt,
  prologue%%    option for package xcolor
]{standalone}
```

should help. Then the package `xcolor` wrote the color table into the PS and then PDF file. Such a special case maybe the use of the documentclass `standalone` which creates a single image which then is included in a document which knows nothing about the color Blue. By the way: Using the `prologue` option in any case doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

*(Not really an answer, but too long for a comment)*

Running `simpdftex latex test`, where `simpdftex` is a wrapper for `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`, I get a Ghostscript error in the `ps2pdf` phase:

```
Error: /undefined in Blue
Operand stack:
   -56.9055
Execution stack:
[...]
```

The PDF is produced and doesn't show the numbers.

However, as soon as I change `Blue` into `blue` or `Blue!100`, the error disappears and the numbers are correctly produced.

The same error happens if I change `Red!20` into `Red` or into another named color without a blending specification.

It seems a bug in the `dvips` driver for PSTricks.

Comment: In my further investigation, `gridlabelcolor` is the source of problem. It cannot accept any colors defined in dvipsnames.

Comment: PSTricks has no driver for colors ...