# Issue on pdf(La)TeX with named colors in dvipsnames

Tags: errors, pdftex, color, pstricks, miktex

When compiled on pdfLaTeX, the following code (and MWE) returns a PostScript error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[pdfcrop={--hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psframe*[linecolor=Maroon](0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The error message reads:

```
/undefined in Maroon
```

and no graphic is generated.

This is related to the `dvipsnames` option and pdfLaTeX, because on the one hand it works fine on XeLaTeX as it is and, on the other, it works fine on pdfLaTeX if I set `svgnames` (which defines a `Maroon` color name) as option for the `xcolor` package.

I have the definitions file `dvipsnam.def`, and a complete MikTeX 2.9 installation running on Windows Xp. I have reinstalled already the `xcolor` package. The issue started all of a sudden after an automated Windows update, but I cannot state that this is the reason behind it. Furthermore, it's the only issue I've detected. Somebody out there has any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excerpt from [texdoc xcolor](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) page 18 and 60 :

> Since version 2.01, `xcolor` offers `prologue` option to write a PostScript header file `xcolor.pro`. This file is as well loaded by `dvips` driver as a prologue, thus making all color names available to the PostScript interpreter.
>
> `prologue` option for comprehensive ‘named’ color support in conjunction
>   with dvips: on-the-fly generation of PostScript prologue files with all color
>   definitions, ready for dvips inclusionand/or post-processing withdevice-specific parameters (e.g., spot colors)

adding `prologue` option while loading`xcolor` works [as suggested by Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74594/15717)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,prologue]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[pdfcrop={--hires}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psframe*[linecolor=Maroon](0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it made it indeed. Now I'm simply wondering why I never had to use it in the past. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Ok, I just saw you set a link to Herbert's remark. I'm still wondering why it had not happened to my files so far, though.

Comment: @Marcos see update