# color with pdfLaTeX and auto-pst-pdf

Tags: pdftex, color, dvips, auto-pst-pdf

a strange problem in using color in pstricks with  auto-pst-pdf, when I use latex +dvips +ps2pdf, the two color name systems (svgnames and dvipsnames) worked well simultaneously, while with pdflatex, only color with svgnames worked, while the colors with dvipsnames disappeared. the dvipsname system for color is not compatible with  auto-pst-pdf?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\psframe[linewidth=0.2pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=AliceBlue](0,0)(0.4,0.3)

\psframe[linewidth=0.2pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Apricot](1,0)(0.4,0.3)

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run this through `pdflatex` I get an error from ghostscript `Error: /undefined in Apricot
Operand stack: ... `

Comment: use the prologue option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38959/2388